# combing IF statements

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

i have a two deep if statement and i'm wondering if i can condense to a single if stmt:

```
if ([[myScrollView.subviews objectAtIndex:k] isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]])
{
    if (((UILabel *)[myScrollView.subviews objectAtIndex:k]).tag >= i)
    {
        //code
    }
}
```

i'm not sure if i can make it into:

```
if ([[myScrollView.subviews objectAtIndex:k] isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]] && ((UILabel *)[myScrollView.subviews objectAtIndex:k]).tag >= i)
```

since the second if condition is dependent on the first (if it is not a UILabel and doesn't have a .tag value) can bad things happen?

Comment: The above comment is completely correct. What do you gain by doing it in one line? You're not making it more efficient, and it's now harder to read. Seriously, fewer lines of code does not mean your code is more efficient.

Comment: ugh, i got hammered for readability. i guess my rationale was one if statement is easier to read then two, but i can see the advantages of having two. i've just always had an aversion to nested if stmt. i'll try to re-evaluate my code's readability and try to improve it.

Comment: An overlooked issue in this example is that you are performing a redundant check as `subview`'s is a `readonly` property, which returns an array of `UIView`'s. `UIView` responds to `tag` so you don't need to check first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can combine them like that, yes. If the first statement fails then it fails the entire `if` statement and doesn't execute the 2nd part.

For ease of reading I would probably write it like this though:

```
if ([[myScrollView.subviews objectAtIndex:k] isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]] && 
    ((UILabel *)[myScrollView.subviews objectAtIndex:k]).tag >= i)
{
    // code
}
```

Answer (score 4):

That's fine. C (and by extension, Objective-C) && expressions are "short-circuiting". If the first clause evaluates to false, the second clause isn't evaluated.

Answer (score 3):

The `&&` operator stops evaluating when it reaches a false clause. So long as the evaluations don't cause any side-effects there shouldn't be any problems.

However, newlines and white-space are your friend for legibility:

```
if ([[myScrollView.subviews objectAtIndex:k] isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]] 
    && ((UILabel *)[myScrollView.subviews objectAtIndex:k]).tag >= i)
{
    //code
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As everyone has identified this is possible but readability is the main issue. Although the use of whitespace in suggestions is good

```
if ([[myScrollView.subviews objectAtIndex:k] isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]] 
&& ((UILabel *)[myScrollView.subviews objectAtIndex:k]).tag >= i)
{
    //code
}
```

I personally would still find I have to do a double take to understand what those statements are doing so sometimes it may be worth taking the readability a bit further

```
UILabel *label      = [myScrollView.subviews objectAtIndex:k]

BOOL isLabel        = [label isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]];
BOOL hasSuitableTag = label.tag >= i;

if (isLabel && hasSuitableTag) {
    //code
}
```

OR to keep the short circuit (Thanks @CocoaFu)

```
UILabel *label = [myScrollView.subviews objectAtIndex:k]

BOOL isLabel   = [label isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]];

if (isLabel && label.tag >= i) {
    //code
}
```

The result reads a bit more like english (if you expand it in your had) `is a label and has a suitable tag`. It may slightly longer but when your reading it back in a weeks time you'll appreciate the added typing.

---

> Programs must be written for people to read, and only incidentally for machines to execute.

Abelson & Sussman, [Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262011530)

Comment: This will crash if the subview k is not a label (no short-circuiting here)

Comment: He is grabbing an object from an array of subviews. All `UIView`'s respond to `tag` I would say this is fairly safe?? `subview`'s is a  readonly property as well so there is no way it can be manipulated to not contain anything other than a `UIView`

Comment: @Paul.s In general I agree but I think the third line is stretching it a little far and loosing the short circuiting. I would drop the `hasSuitableTag` line and make the if: `if (isLabel && label.tag >= i)`. Clear, reads well and still short circuits.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it the second way. Basically, in an AND statement the compiler will check the first statement and if it is false it won't check the second statement... so the second/inner statement only gets evaluated when the first statement is true.